# Creating an aggregate function fails

Tags: aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.1

While looking for an aggregate function that returns the nth element of a collection I found the following solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _final_nth( anyarray, integer )
  RETURNS anyelement AS
$BODY$
    SELECT a
    FROM unnest( $1 ) a
    ORDER BY a
    offset $2
    LIMIT 1;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'sql' IMMUTABLE; 

CREATE AGGREGATE nth( anyelement, integer ) (
  SFUNC=array_append,
  STYPE=anyarray,
  FINALFUNC=_final_nth,
  INITCOND='{}'
);
```

Creating the function works fine but executing CREATE AGGREGATE produces the following error:

> ERROR:  function array_append(anyarray, anyelement, integer) does not exist

I am not able to resolve this error.

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of this question. You say you want the nth element of a collection, but what's a "collection" in PG? If a "collection" is a result set, what's wrong with a straight `OFFSET`/`LIMIT`, and if it's an array, what's wrong with a straight `myarray[n]`? Why do you need an aggregate at all? Also, the error looks pretty obvious to me. PostgreSQL is trying to pass the current state plus the aggregate's arguments to the `SFUNC`, and there's no `array_append` that takes those arguments (nor would it make any sense for there to be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION _final_nth( anyarray, integer )
  RETURNS anyelement AS
$BODY$
    SELECT a
    FROM unnest( $1 ) a
    ORDER BY a
    offset $2
    LIMIT 1;
$BODY$
```

Use it without an extra aggregate-function.

```
SELECT _final_nth(array_agg(someelement),n) AS someelement
FROM sometable
GROUP BY someelement;
```

n is the offset.